# Space in the root folder name

Tags: directory, dreamweaver, root

I created a website to replace our current company site using dreamweaver. The website is fully functional when previewed within dreamweaver. I uploaded the files to Network Solutions with no issues. Here is where I believe I messed up...the websites folder name has a space in it. When I attempted to point one of our unused domains to the new website folder "/htdocs/Jeff Jr" the system would not accept the space between Jeff and Jr. I then put it as "/htdocs/JeffJr" and the site isn't showing up.

Is there a character that will read as a space? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should not use spaces, uppercase characters, or anything other than just text and maybe an underscore here and there.  I make the point about uppercase because SEO says it's a bad idea.  And it is.  Linux systems are case sensative.  So it is an issue.  And, really the space is particularly dangerous.

The thing is with DreamWeaver is that it's running its stuff locally, and the file system is automatically resolving pathnames.  So because the system allows badly formed pathnames, DreamWeaver will work just fine.  But you will run into a problem when you move it live.

Comment: It's looking like my only option is to change the name of the file and redirect in dreamweaver...then re-upload?

Comment: Well, yeah.  Because ultimately, it's far more important for the server side to be set up correctly.  Worry about DreamWeaver later.